# Record webcam MP4 fragments with FFMPEG: only first file has video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to record my webcam, but the recording to have segments of 10 seconds. So, I want to record fragments (countinuously) of 10 seconds from my webcam. I am a beginner of FFMPEG so I've started to search how to do this. I found some ffmpeg commands and the command bellow seems to be ok, but I have a problem: it starts recording and saves files but I can only open the first file and see the webcam with audio. The other files are only audio (tried tot open with vlc and windows media player).

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -s 352x288 -i video="USB Video Device":audio="Microphone (USB Audio Device)" -vcodec h264 -acodec libmp3lame -map 0 -r 10 -f segment -segment_time 10 dummy_out%03d.mp4
```

Please tell me if you need more info. As I am a beginner I don't know if I must post any other things here. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because all other files (without first) are not starting from time 0, and that's why the video player doesn't know how to play the video file.

You should add `-reset_timestamps 1` to make it working:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -s 640x360 -i video="USB Video Device":audio="Microphone (USB Audio Device)" -vcodec h264 -acodec libmp3lame -map 0 -r 15 -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 dummy_out%03d.mp4
```